# Quarkus - Generate rest clients from OpenApi

Tags: openapi, quarkus, openapi-generator

I'm using Quarkus with Kotlin and tried to generate Rest clients using this Quarkus extension https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-openapi-generator.

I included the dependency and the mentioned plugin into the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkiverse.openapi.generator</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-openapi-generator</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>build</goal>
        <goal>generate-code</goal>
        <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

When compiling everything gets generated correctly into `target/openapi/quarkus/clients_json/api/DefaultApi.java`

However, when trying to import the `DefaultApi` it throws an error that it can't find the class.

I've tried the suggestions from the following post [maven can't add files in generated-sources for compilation phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121010/maven-cant-add-files-in-generated-sources-for-compilation-phase?rq=1) and included

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/gen-java</source><!-- adjust folder name to your needs -->
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

into the pom.xml as well but it didn't do anything.

Does anyone know how to change the output directory of the generated OpenApi files with Quarkus?

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI:

I did the following, and it worked

```
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/openapi</source>
            <source>src/gen/java</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

While my answer is short, and you managed to solve your problem - a lot of other people were also having issues with generated sources not showing up for imports or auto-complete in Eclipse, I tried the recommendations such as checking the settings for auto complete in the editor, close the project and reopen it.  Check and tweak the source settings under properties.  Nothing did the trick until I completely closed eclipse and reopened it.

Just wanted to put this here in case anyone else runs into a similar issue!